# Yii framework radiobuttonlist

Tags: php, yii, radiobuttonlist

Can anyone shine a light on how to determine which radio button has been selected when the form has been submitted?

I am using `CActiveForm::radioButtonList`?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to determine it. Client will transmit its value in `POST` data.

For example such code

```
<?=$form->radioButtonList($person,'gender_code',array('m'=>'Male','f'=>'Female')); ?>
```

will form `POST[gender_code]=m`  or `POST[gender_code]=f`

Answer (score 4):

Radio List Reflects simple form Submitting process. If you have following list implementation for example

```
 <div class="form">
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>     
    <div class="row">
        <?php
            echo CHtml::radioButtonList(
                    'registerMode',
                    'consumer',
                    array(
                        'consumer'=>'I am a FOODIE ',
                        'staff'=>'I want to give Services ',
                    ),
                    array('template'=>'<div class="rb">{input}</div><div class="rb">{label}</div><div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>')
                );
        ?>
    </div>     
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Register',array('class'=>'submit')); ?>
    </div>

<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
</div><!-- form -->
```

when submitted following input is generated

```
array
(
    'registerMode' => 'consumer'
    'yt0' => 'Register'
)
```

it represents name or Index of the option Selected

following code can get values

```
  if(isset($_POST['registerMode']))
         CVarDumper::Dump($_POST['registerMode'],100,true);
```

Good Luck

Comment: +1 for template, I've ended up with `'template' => '<div class="gRadio">{input}{label}</div>'` :)

Comment: OP asked about radioButtonList() method in CActiveForm not CHtml.